# Grails startup process

Tags: grails

Is there documentation anywhere describing how grails initializes?

What happens when you do a `grails run-app`:  What's the process [and developer hooks] of starting the servlet container, starting plugins, properties, mapping domain objects and resources which ends with the controllers initialized and serving requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that [this blog post](https://justlearningdotcom.wordpress.com/2012/12/02/grails-bootstrap-under-the-hood/comment-page-1/) can help you.

Comment: Awesome, thank you -- googling for "grails bootstrap" wasn't helping me at all!

Comment: This blog post is no longer active